# How can I add the 3 minimum values in a Column in an Access Report but Display all the Values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am working on an Access report and Need to find the Sum of the Three Minimum Values in a Displayed report. All the Other values must be displayed too.

Comment: Hi Welcome Samuel, can you give us some example data please. We work better with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider options:

1. build a query object `SELECT TOP 3 fieldname FROM tablename ORDER BY [fieldname]` then DSum() expression in textbox to sum that query
2. report RecordSource uses Cartesian association of table and query to show the sum on each record then that field can be placed in report header or footer textbox

```
    SELECT tablename.*, SumMin FROM tablename, (SELECT Sum(fieldname) AS SumMin 
        FROM (SELECT TOP 3 fieldname FROM tablename ORDER BY fieldname)) AS Q;
```

3. three textboxes on report with following settings - report must order records by field to sum

Two textboxes in Detail section - can be not visible.

Name: tbxSeq
RunningSum: Over All
ControlSource: =1

Name: tbxSum
RunningSum: Over All
ControlSource: =IIf([tbxSeq]<=3,[fieldname],0)

Textbox in report header or footer:

ControlSource: =tbxSum

Sample data:
15
20
20
25
The sum will be 55 with each method.

Comment: Thanks So Much I used the Third one and It worked perfectly for me